# center overflowed view on given element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

With ReactJs i'm creating an horizontal timeline with dates.

For example i have a list of 100 elements and each one have a date and text content.

I display all the dates horizontaly (with `flex-direction="row"` and `overflowX: "auto"`)
and verticaly all the content with date + text content styled etc.

[image]

Now when i click on a date in the `"horizontal date TimeLine"` the page scroll to the corresponding content with anchor-link (not showed in the following gif ) and when i scroll the page over contents, the corresponding dates in the  `"horizontal date TimeLine"` become red to track where we are.

The problem is i want to center or scroll the "current date" ( for example '02/07' ) in the `"horizontal date TimeLine"`, for the moment i have to use the horizontal scroll manually.

I have no idea how to scroll horizontally inside the `overflow-ed` div without using anchor.

any tips to do this with element's index or id ?
thanks

Comment: Any chance you can put together a MRE with maybe 10 tiles so we can debug this together over CodeSandbox? I have a hunch on how you can get the top section to horizontally scroll `onClick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a very simple solution i found : `scrollIntoView`

```
 var element = document.getElementById(idOfElementToScrollTo);

    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest", inline: "center"});
    }
```